# Accordion/More Info within table row using bootstrap3, asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

does anyone know if it is possible to expand a table row? I guess using something along the lines of Accordion or collapse? Within my row (as below) i have a field called notes that has a large amount of text.

[image: Click for my table row with notes section]

I am looking for a way to show a certain amount of words then trail off with more... this would then be clickable and expands the row to see the full notes field.

Any help/push in the right direction (or even confirmation to say it is possible) would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: Share your code or make an online demo/snippet, so that it is easy to help you.